What kind of chair is this?
It's low. Probably only a toddler could stand up easily.

It's not a chair; it's a stool. More specifically, a 'step stool'. Used by adults and children to stand on to reach something otherwise inaccessible. The hole in the top is there so that an adult can pick it up with one hand.

What is it called in your language? Is it just a chair? This question was answerable using a bi-lingual dictionary or at the very least explaining us why you think "stool" isn't an accurate term. what makes you think every piece of furniture or architectural feature has a different word in American English and in Canadian English?

You're unlucky because if ELL had twenty, thirty questions a day your posts would go unnoticed or be ignored by users who would find more interesting questions to answer but as it is, many of your questions consist of a single line or two.  You obviously have the skill and intelligence to do at least some research yourself and share it with everyone.

Pardon, I think I have confused you with someone else, whose style of writing is similar to yours.

@Mari-LouA - someone else who also seeks to restrict answers to American English and Canadian English?

@MichaelHarvey haven't you noticed? Click on the tags. It might be coincidental there have been several questions focused on American and Canadian English recently or it might not be. Regardless, having two accounts is permitted on Stack Exchange, it's only when a user has been banned from posting questions, due to low quality, and creates a new account ad hoc to circumvent the ban that is expressly forbidden and could earn the user a suspension.

@Mari-LouA -I was trying to be oblique. I have had a fair idea who the OP is for at least a week.

@MichaelHarvey  On the Internet it's difficult to know whether something is said with a wink or genuine stupor.

@MichaelHarvey Though short, your first comment seems substantial enough to be an answer and seems like the best one. Perhaps the missing ingredient is that, yes, a stool can be sat on; some stools are even primarily for seating (bar stool, "three-legged stool" in olden cottages, etc.), so just because a toddler might sit on something like this doesn't preclude the use of the word "stool." (I guess it's more about not having a back?)

This is the kind of mistake an interpreter should never make : "Probably only a toddler could stand up easily". when what is meant is: "Probably only a toddler could stand up easily on it". You persist in asking about irrelevant AmE and CanE differences. The differences do not occur in these types of words/terms. However, Canadian spelling has differences with AmE and BrE.

@Mari-LouA This OP claims s/he wants to be a conference interpreter. Right. So that is what I am. I wrote three long posts in another question in general about that and about CanE and AmE. Guess what? No response, but a name change. I also, like you, did ask him/her  to please provide research and did so nicely and politely. The response was to argue with me. Until gotube stepped in and repeated the request re research. So you know what? I'm so done. :)

The item in the picture is not a chair; it is a stool. More specifically, a 'step stool' These are often used by adults and children to stand on to reach something otherwise inaccessible. The hole in the top is there so that an adult can pick it up with one hand.
The difference between a chair and a stool is that a chair has a 'back' (or back rest), and possibly 'arms' (or arm rests) - a stool does not have any of these.
